# Parsing an expression for coefficients and more

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, expression-manipulation

I have many expressions of this form:

```
expression = 1/96 (-26 I + 15 Sqrt[3]) c[1] - c[1]^3/(8 Sqrt[3]) + 
 1/120 I c[1]^5 + 5/96 (-5 I + 2 Sqrt[3]) c[3] + 
 1/480 (11 I + 135 Sqrt[3]) c[5]
```

For each c[a]^b term, I want to form a tuple with the coefficient to c[a]^b, argument of c[a]^b which is a, and power of c[a]^b which is b.
I want a list of all these tuples.

So for this example, I want a function of  `expression` that returns
`{{1/96 (-26 I + 15 Sqrt[3]), 1,1},{1/(8 Sqrt[3]),1,3},...}`

How do I do this with Mathematica?

Comment: Try `CoefficientRules[expression, Array[c, 5]]`. The format of the output is a bit different what you asked for. But maybe it suits your needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
expression = 
  1/96 (-26 I + 15 Sqrt[3]) c[1] - c[1]^3/(8 Sqrt[3]) + 
   1/120 I c[1]^5 + 5/96 (-5 I + 2 Sqrt[3]) c[3] + 
   1/480 (11 I + 135 Sqrt[3]) c[5];

Cases[expression, coef_. * c[a_]^b_. :> {coef, a, b}, 1]

(* {{1/96 (-26 I + 15 Sqrt[3]), 1, 1}, 
    {-(1/(8 Sqrt[3])), 1, 3}, 
    {I/120, 1, 5}, 
    {5/96 (-5 I + 2 Sqrt[3]), 3, 1}, 
    {1/480 (11 I + 135 Sqrt[3]), 5, 1}} *)
```

**EDIT:** See the documentation for [`Default`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Default.html):  "_. represents an argument that can be omitted" In this case, `coef_.` defaults to `1`; `b_.` also defaults to `1`

```
Default[Times]

(* 1 *)

Default[Power, 2]

(* 1 *)
```

**EDIT 2:** The example in your latest comment fails because the target is the whole expression rather than a part.

```
expr = 2 I c[1] Sin[Pi/7];

Cases[expr, coef_. * c[a_]^b_. :> {coef, a, b}, 1]

(* {{1, 1, 1}} *)
```

Since any result won't be affected by adding an arbitrary constant (say `1`), do that for **any** input.

```
Cases[1 + expr, coef_. * c[a_]^b_. :> {coef, a, b}, 1]

(* {{2 I Sin[π/7], 1, 1}} *)
```

Comment: Beautiful, thank you!

Comment: what's the dot do? eg b_. ?

Comment: Also, I dont think this answer is fully right - it doesn't work for instance with `1/4 Sqrt[3] c[1] - 1/6 I c[1]^3 + 1/12 (8 I + 3 Sqrt[3]) c[3]`, where I would have expected 3 tuples to be present, instead of just 2

Comment: @MondoDuke  `coef_// FullForm` gives `Pattern[coef, Blank[]]`, `coef_. // FullForm` gives `Optional[Pattern[coef, Blank[]]]`

Comment: Your second example works fine for me. I get `{{Sqrt[3]/4, 1, 1}, {-(I/6), 1, 3}, {1/12 (8 I + 3 Sqrt[3]), 3, 1}}`

Comment: You are right, it was something on my end.

Answer (score 2):

```
1/96 (-26 I + 15 Sqrt[3]) c[1] - c[1]^3/(8 Sqrt[3]) + 
1/120 I c[1]^5 + 5/96 (-5 I + 2 Sqrt[3]) c[3] + 
1/480 (11 I + 135 Sqrt[3]) c[5] //
Apply[List]//
Map[Replace[coef_. * c[a_]^b_. :> {coef, a, b}]]
```

> `{{(-26*I + 15*Sqrt[3])/96, 1, 1}, {-1/(8*Sqrt[3]), 1, 3}, {I/120, 1, 5}, {(5*(-5*I + 2*Sqrt[3]))/96, 3, 1}, {(11*I + 135*Sqrt[3])/480, 5, 1}}`

also

```
1/4 Sqrt[3] c[1] - 1/6 I c[1]^3 + 1/12 (8 I + 3 Sqrt[3]) c[3]//
Apply[List]//
Map[Replace[coef_. * c[a_]^b_. :> {coef, a, b}]]
```

> `{{Sqrt[3]/4, 1, 1}, {-I/6, 1, 3}, {(8*I + 3*Sqrt[3])/12, 3, 1}}`

meets your need.

Answer (score 2):

Another way, as the comment @Henrik Schumacher said:

```
first = Function[t,FirstPosition[t , _?(# != 0 &)] ];
forKey = {first@#, Total@#}&;

CoefficientRules[1/4 Sqrt[3]c[1] - 1/6 I c[1]^3 + 1/12(8 I + 3 Sqrt[3]) c[3], Array[c, 5]]//
Association //
KeyValueMap[{#2,forKey@#1}&]//
Map[Flatten]
```

> `{{-I/6, 1, 3}, {Sqrt[3]/4, 1, 1}, {(2*I)/3 + Sqrt[3]/4, 3, 1}}`